# How to do MySQL "IN" condition query with JSON_EXTRACT?

Tags: mysql, json-extract

I have a table similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `foo_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`)
);
```

insert some data

```
insert into foo(data, data_type, data_status) values ('{\"id\": \"FOO\", \"code\": \"FOO\"}', 1, 1);
insert into foo(data, data_type, data_status) values ('{\"id\": \"BAR\", \"code\": \"BAR\"}', 1, 1);
insert into foo(data, data_type, data_status) values ('{\"id\": \"BAZ\", \"code\": \"BAZ\"}', 1, 1);
```

show table contents:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+--------+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| foo_id | data                         | data_type | data_status |
+--------+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
|      1 | {"id": "FOO", "code": "FOO"} |         1 |           1 |
|      2 | {"id": "BAR", "code": "BAR"} |         1 |           1 |
|      3 | {"id": "BAZ", "code": "BAZ"} |         1 |           1 |
+--------+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This query works:

```
select f.data, f.data_type, f.data_status
from foo f
where (JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.code') in ('FOO'))
   and (f.data_type in (1)) 
   and (f.data_status in (1));

+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| data                         | data_type | data_status |
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| {"id": "FOO", "code": "FOO"} |         1 |           1 |
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This one too:

```
select f.data, f.data_type, f.data_status
from foo f
where (JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.code') in ('BAR'))
   and (f.data_type in (1)) 
   and (f.data_status in (1));

+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| data                         | data_type | data_status |
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| {"id": "BAR", "code": "BAR"} |         1 |           1 |
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

This one does not however...

```
select f.data, f.data_type, f.data_status
from foo f
where (JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.code') in ('FOO','BAR'))
   and (f.data_type in (1)) 
   and (f.data_status in (1));

Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

How can I make the third query work?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed there was a warning on the last query

```
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

...

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                           |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1235 | This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'comparison of JSON in the IN operator' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

However, that warning led me to this post

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93800

So, by modifying the query to surround the IN arguments with quotes, it works

```
select f.data, f.data_type, f.data_status 
from foo f 
where (JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.code') in ('"FOO"','"BAR"'))    
and (f.data_type in (1))     
and (f.data_status in (1));
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| data                         | data_type | data_status |
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| {"id": "FOO", "code": "FOO"} |         1 |           1 |
| {"id": "BAR", "code": "BAR"} |         1 |           1 |
+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

still got the same warning though...

The solution only works for more than one IN parameter, it breaks if you try it on the first two queries that initially succeeded

```
mysql> select f.data, f.data_type, f.data_status 
from foo f 
where (JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.code') in ('"BAR"'))    
and (f.data_type in (1))     
and (f.data_status in (1));
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: To avoid the quotes you can also use `JSON_UNQUOTE` like so `(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.code')) in ('BAR'))`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path